# HAML - how do I make a path that makes the browser go back in a button?

Tags: haml

I currently have a button like this:

```
= button_to "Go Back" , mobile_disclosures_url , :method => :get
```

But I am not sure what path to give it so that it makes the browser go back.  Any help? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JS for a real browser based backward navigation.

```
= button_to "Go Back", '#', :onclick => 'history.back(); return false;'
```

From memory, I think works with `button_to`, but it should definitely work with `link_to`.

Comment: Yes that worked only with link_to and button_to didnt seem to work.

Comment: Btw I looked at your site thebeautifulpixel - its pretty cool :)

Answer (score 1):

```
=link_to "Go Back", :back
```

and it will set the link to the REFERER header

Comment: This worked. I use ruby on rails HAML gem. The other answer was more complicated but I liked this one and to add onto it it worked.